# NoMethodError when attempting to implement a contact us form using mailer rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, nomethoderror

I'm relatively new to rails and I'm stuggling to wrap my head about many things. But right now mostly the ActionMailer. Im trying to build a contact us form.

Im currently getting this error

```
NoMethodError in ContactsController#new
private method `new' called for Contact:Class
  def new
      @contact = Contact.new
  end
```

This is my mailers/contact.rb

```
1 class Contact < ActionMailer::Base
2   default from: "my@email.com"
3
4
5   def contact_us(subject)
6     mail(to: 'my@email.com', subject: subject)
7   end
8
9 end
```

this is my contacts_controller.rb

```
1 class ContactsController < ApplicationController
2   def new
3     @contact = Contact.new
4   end
5
6   def create
7     @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
8   #Tell the contact model to send contact_us
9     if Contact.contact_us(subject).deliver
10       flash.now[:error] = nil
11       flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
12     else
13       flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
14       render :new
15     end
16   end
17 private
18  def contact_params
19   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
20  end
21 end
```

and finally this is views

```
1 <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
2   <p>
3     <%=f.input :name %>
4   </p>
5   <p>
6     <%=f.input :email %>
7     </p>
8   <p>
9     <%=f.text_area :message %>
10   </p>
11   <p>
12     <%= f.submit %>
13   </p>
14 <%end%>
15
```

I know the solution is probably right ahead. But I would really appreciate some help if possible. 
Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different things going on in your code. First of all if you inherit from `ActionMailer::Base` you are creating a Mailer class, not an ActiveRecord model. I would rename that class `ContactMailer` or just use one `Mailer` for the entire app and call it Mailer.

This is also the reason you cannot call `Contact.new`. If your Contact class inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` you could call `new` on the model and instantiate an instance of that object. But with mailers you are defining class methods, each one defined to send a particular email. You don't ever need to create a new instance of an object that inherits from ActionMailer.

Let's say you had a class `Mailer < ActionMailer::Base` and in that class you have a method `def contact_us(subject)` you would call:

```
Mailer.contact_us(subject).deliver
```

To send the email.